# How to use google/zx to execute ffmpeg shell in windows?

Tags: node.js, shell, ffmpeg

I download the ffmpeg through scoop,and I can use ffmpeg in powershell.

My script is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zx
const filePath = `./abc.mp4`;
const srsServerURL = `192.168.30.100`;
await $`ffmpeg -re -i ${filePath} -c copy -f mp4 -y rtmp://${srsServerURL}/live/livestream`;
```

but the zx tell me that ffmpeg not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue might be that zx is using the bash inside WSL. Assuming you also don't want to use ffmpeg in WSL, here is how I fixed it.

1. Install git.
2. Find the `bash.exe` inside the installed git. In my case, it is located at `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe`.
3. Insert the following line after the shebang: `` $.shell = `Location to your bash` ``. In my case, it is `` $.shell = `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe`; ``.

I am fairly sure this works with other distributions of bash for Windows, but I have not tested.